# How to restrict application to registered device

Tags: javascript, angular, nodes

My application requires that it can be accessed only to registered devices. It cannot be accessed using devices not registered.

Users are either issued company phone or company laptop. Application may only be used using his/her registered device.

Example, the device ID is saved in relation to registered username. The application  may only be allowed to login using the saved device ID.

Comment: JavaScript has no access to hardware information like that. Also, _"The user will then be automatically logged out if he accesses from another device."_ Makes no sense... Why would a user even be logged in when switching devices? How would the new device know who the user is?

Comment: the idea is, the user can only login to 1 and only 1 specific device.

Answer (score 1):

Client's JavaScript can not access to device hardware information, so you can not check it on client-side.
But you can do the following:

1. When user try to access OR login at your site/application, you can pass the data about this user to backend-side.
2. Handle and decide can user proceed or not at backend-side. You have different options and ways how to do it:

- you can match the user's access data with allowed data(by user GUID/ID + relation with device ID, it's up to you when you have the data);
- you can **restrict the network** and check the IP range etc.